# Add a geom_smooth() before grouping the data in a ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse

My ggplot below works great. However, I was wondering how to add a regression line ***before*** grouping my `dat` by `group_by(groups)`, that is a `geom_smooth()` on the entire `dat` (*see pic below*)?

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/cw2.csv')
dat$groups <- factor(dat$groups)

dat2 <- dat %>% group_by(groups) %>% summarize(mean_x = mean(x),
                                       mean_y = mean(y),
                                       .groups = 'drop')


dat %>% group_by(groups) %>% ggplot() +  ## @@ BEFORE group_by(group) can I add a geom_smooth()
  aes(x, y, color = groups, shape = groups)+
  geom_point(size = 2) + theme_classic()+ 
  stat_ellipse(level = .6) +
  geom_point(data = dat2, 
             mapping = aes(x = mean_x, y = mean_y,fill = factor(groups)),
             size = 4, show.legend = F,shape=21) +
  geom_smooth(data = dat2, mapping = aes(x = mean_x, y = mean_y,group=1), 
              method = "lm", se=F, color = 1, formula = 'y ~ x')+
  scale_fill_manual(values=rep('black',3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
dat %>% group_by(groups) %>% ggplot() +  ## @@ BEFORE group_by(group) can I add a geom_smooth()
  aes(x, y, color = groups, shape = groups)+
  geom_point(size = 2) + theme_classic()+ 
  geom_smooth(formula = "y~x",aes(group=1),se=F,color='black')+
  stat_ellipse(level = .6) +
  geom_point(data = dat2, 
             mapping = aes(x = mean_x, y = mean_y,color = factor(groups)),
             size = 4, show.legend = F) +
  geom_smooth(data = dat2, mapping = aes(x = mean_x, y = mean_y,group=1), 
              method = "lm", se=F, color = 1, formula = 'y ~ x')
```

Output:

[image]

Or using **@stefan** concept (Which is great):

```
#Code 2
dat %>% group_by(groups) %>% ggplot() +  ## @@ BEFORE group_by(group) can I add a geom_smooth()
  aes(x, y, color = groups, shape = groups)+
  geom_point(size = 2) + theme_classic()+ 
  geom_smooth(method='lm',formula = "y~x",aes(group=1),se=F,color='black')+
  stat_ellipse(level = .6) +
  geom_point(data = dat2, 
             mapping = aes(x = mean_x, y = mean_y,color = factor(groups)),
             size = 4, show.legend = F) +
  geom_smooth(data = dat2, mapping = aes(x = mean_x, y = mean_y,group=1), 
              method = "lm", se=F, color = 1, formula = 'y ~ x')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I have one more follow up left:-)

Comment: Hi Duck, [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64626743/7223434) is my follow-up. There is an answer but I wonder if we can achieve my goal there using `tidyverse` itself?

Answer (score 2):

This could be achieved like so:

BTW: Grouping your dataset has no effect on the plot. The `group`s are determined by the aesthetics.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/cw2.csv')
dat$groups <- factor(dat$groups)

dat2 <- dat %>% group_by(groups) %>% summarize(mean_x = mean(x),
                                               mean_y = mean(y),
                                               .groups = 'drop')


dat %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x, y, color = groups, shape = groups)+
  geom_point(size = 2) + theme_classic()+ 
  stat_ellipse(level = .6) +
  geom_point(data = dat2, 
             mapping = aes(x = mean_x, y = mean_y,fill = factor(groups)),
             size = 4, show.legend = F,shape=21) +
  geom_smooth(data = dat2, mapping = aes(x = mean_x, y = mean_y,group=1), 
          method = "lm", se=F, color = 1, formula = 'y ~ x')+ 
  geom_smooth(aes(group = 1), 
              method = "lm", se=F, color = 2, formula = 'y ~ x')+
  scale_fill_manual(values=rep('black',3))
```

[image]

Comment: Oops. Sorry. You can simply add your geom_smooth. I will fix it.