# Adding an additional legend manually for different data.frames used in the same ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse

In my plot below, I have two separate sources of `data` (`dat` and `dat2`) used in two different `geom_smooth()` calls producing the black and the red regression lines (*see pic below*).

Is it possible to manually add another `legend` that shows the black line is called `"Between"` and red line is called `"Within"`?

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/cw2.csv')
dat$groups <- factor(dat$groups)

dat2 <- dat %>% group_by(groups) %>% summarize(mean_x = mean(x),
                                               mean_y = mean(y),
                                               .groups = 'drop')
dat %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x, y, color = groups, shape = groups)+
  geom_point(size = 2) + theme_classic()+ 
  stat_ellipse(level = .6) +
  geom_point(data = dat2, 
             mapping = aes(x = mean_x, y = mean_y,fill = factor(groups)),
             size = 4, show.legend = F,shape=21) +
  geom_smooth(data = dat2, mapping = aes(x = mean_x, y = mean_y,group=1), 
          method = "lm", se=F, color = 1, formula = 'y ~ x')+ 
  geom_smooth(aes(group = 1), 
              method = "lm", se=F, color = 2, formula = 'y ~ x')+
  scale_fill_manual(values=rep('black',3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you need a second color scale to do this. You can use the `ggnewscale` package:

```r
library(ggnewscale)

dat %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x, y, color = groups, shape = groups) +
  geom_point(size = 2) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  stat_ellipse(level = .6) +
  geom_point(data = dat2, 
             mapping = aes(x = mean_x, y = mean_y),
             size = 4, show.legend = FALSE, shape = 21, fill = "black") +
  scale_color_discrete() +
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_smooth(data = dat2, 
              mapping = aes(x = mean_x, y = mean_y, group = 1, color = "black"), 
          method = "lm", se = FALSE, formula = 'y ~ x') + 
  geom_smooth(aes(group = 1, color = "red"), 
              method = "lm", se = FALSE, formula = 'y ~ x') +
  scale_color_identity(name = "", labels = c("Between", "Within"),
                       guide = guide_legend())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Allan. But is it possible to create a completely manual legend as is the case with BASE R `legend()` in `ggplot2`? I will be OK with something close what I described.

Comment: @morouzian see my update. The way ggplot2 works is that it insists anything you display in a legend has to be mapped to some aesthetic in the plot. It's actually a very sensible way to do things, and less error-prone than manually creating a legend. It's also much more flexible than you'd imagine. There is almost never a need to "manually" build a legend. You can see here that I have effectively done that anyway, but using ggplot's system. I have specified the names, colors, titles and produced the desired result.

Comment: Accepted, but not sure if I would completely agree with your last comment, analyst must be given the freedom that s/he needs as well. Also, it seems kind of ridiculous that to simply add a legend a completely new R package would be required, something I really wanted to avoid.

Comment: @morouzian my point was that you can build a legend quite easily and transparently this way. You don't _need_ a different package. There are other ways to do it but they are longer and more cumbersome. Still, the ability to add extra Color scales is definitely a shortcoming in ggplot. That's what the new package helps with.